# I need to reverse several letters and stop printing several lines of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice, reverse

I need to reserve a few letters. The code that I have keeps duplicates extra rows and columns.  I'm not sure what I need to adjust to make the code work correctly.
The code is written in python.

```
def find_pairs(words):

  word_set = set(words)
     # Initialize a set to store the symmetric pairs of words
  result = set()
     # Iterate through each word in the set
  for word in word_set:
        # Create the reverse of the word
          reverse = word[::-1]
          if reverse in word_set and word != reverse:
            # Add the word and its reverse to the result set
            result.add(f"{word} & {reverse}")
  for pair in result:
          print(pair)

# Test the function with different test cases and print the result
find_pairs(["am","at","ma","if","fi"])      # ma & am, fi & if
print("=============")
find_pairs(["ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "ba"])  # ba & ab
print("=============")
find_pairs(["ab","ba","ac","ad","da","ca"]) # ba & ab, da & ad, ca & ac
print("=============")
find_pairs(["ab", "ac"])                    # None
print("=============")
find_pairs(["ab", "aa", "ba"])              # ba & ab
print("=============")
find_pairs(["23","84","49","13","32","46","91","99","94","31","57","14"])
                                            # 32 & 23, 94 & 49, 31 & 13
```

I tried to change the number within to reduce duplicates lines of code - no improvement.
reverse = word[::-1]

The second goal was to change add to update. Updates reduced the number of lines but did not print out the full code.

result.add(f"{word} & {reverse}")
The original code made more duplicates, so I discarded that one.

```
# for words in words:
    #     reverse = ""
    #     reverse = words[1] + words[0]
    #     print(words, reverse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the formatted string in the `result` set, just store one of the two values (use `max` to make sure it's always the same one added) then format it after

```py
def find_pairs(words):
    word_set = set(words)
    # Initialize a set to store the symmetric pairs of words
    result = set()
    # Iterate through each word in the set
    for word in word_set:
        # Create the reverse of the word
        reverse = word[::-1]
        if reverse in word_set and word != reverse:
            # Add the maximum of word and reverse to the result set
            result.add(max(word, reverse))
    for word in result:
        # print out the formatted version
        print(f"{word} & {word[::-1]}")
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the code as you recommended, I will research the max and figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar answer to @Samathingamajig, but instead of using max I just add a check in the if statement if the reverse is already in result. The only difference would be their version would attempt to add it to the set, which would fail if it exists, whereas mine would check if the reverse exists and not attempt to add it at all.

```
def find_pairs(words):
    word_set = set(words)
    # Initialize a set to store the symmetric pairs of words
    result = set()
    # Iterate through each word in the set
    for word in word_set:
        # Create the reverse of the word
        reverse = word[::-1]
        if reverse in word_set and word != reverse and reverse not in result:
            # Add the word and its reverse to the result set
            result.add(word)
    for word in result:
        reverse = word[::-1]
        print(f"{word} & {reverse}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the lines of code, this is shorter:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_pairs(words):
  return [k for k, v in Counter(map(lambda w: "{} & {}".format(
      *sorted([w, w[::-1]])), words)).items() if v > 1]
```

Comment: Thank you Hlidka! That is shorter compared to mine code. I will research how to use counter and lambda.